sp-io v38.0.0 cannot find function `malloc` in module `crate::allocator`
I'm building custom solochain using polkadot-sdk-solochain-template.
After I've added some dependencies and fixed error with implementation I'm starting to get the sp-io error:
cannot find function `malloc` in module `crate::allocator`
      --> /home/viktor/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/sp-io-38.0.0/src/global_alloc_wasm.rs:28:21
       |
  28   |         crate::allocator::malloc(layout.size() as u32)
       |                           ^^^^^^ not found in `crate::allocator`
       |

Cargo.toml:
sp-io = { version = "38.0.0", default-features = false }

So, that's not my issue, looks like something went wrong inside sp-io, but maybe I forgot to add any features or something else?
